# What query should I use?

Tags: sql, join, union

I have condition to my query, I want to create the query result like these

```
ID  Name    Address ID  Name    Address
1   Dono    x1  1   Dono    x1
2   Kasino  x2  2   Kasino  x2
3   Indro   x3  3   Indro   x3
4   Nano    x4  4   Nano    x4
```

The data is came from one table with same select queries, but when I use `Union All` it didn't give me the result like I want

Here's my queries

`select * from table x
union all
select * from table x`

what kind of `select` statement should I use?

Comment: Why would you want to repeat the same field twice in the row?

Comment: Why you need duplicate fields for?

Comment: Why are you duplicating the columns ?
any specific reason ..

Answer (score 1):

```
select ID, Name, Address, ID, Name, Address from table x;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
select id, name, address, id, name, address from x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, * FROM x
```

This seems odd, but it works. What more seems odd, is your requirement for such a result.

`UNION ALL` is used to concatenate ***rows*** from different queries, not columns.

Answer (score 1):

The query you need is...

```
select ID, [Name], [Address], ID, [Name], [Address] from Your_Tab
```